# Navigation stack on an Atom CPU: possible?

Tags: ros, navigation, performance

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

We're working on getting the Navigation [stack](http://wiki.ros.org/navigation/Tutorials/RobotSetup) up-and-running on our [robot](https://projects.cecs.pdx.edu/projects/roboticsclub-mcecsbot/wiki). We're making headway, but we have a question about the horsepower needed to run the nav stack. We're working under the assumption that [this](http://www.terasic.com.tw/cgi-bin/page/archive.pl?Language=English&CategoryNo=11&No=529) computer will do the trick. The DE2i-150 has an Atom N2600 at 1.6 GHz and 2GB of DDR3 RAM. Is this a reasonable assumption?

Thanks in advance,

Rick Armstrong

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/162681/navigation-stack-on-an-atom-cpu:-possible?/) by [Rick Armstrong](https://answers.ros.org/users/13391/rick-armstrong/) on ROS Answers with karma: 567 on 2014-05-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It appears the [Atom N2600 is roughly comparable to the Atom D525](http://cpuboss.com/cpus/Intel-Atom-N2600-vs-Intel-Atom-D525) originally used with the netbooks sold with the Turtlebot (eeePC 1215n). It thus should be possible to run the navigation stack on the machine you mentioned.

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2014-05-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Rick Armstrong](https://answers.ros.org/users/13391/rick-armstrong/) on 2014-05-07**:
Thanks, Stefan.

**Comment by [fergs](https://answers.ros.org/users/84/fergs/) on 2014-05-09**:
I would definitely look at the turtlebot nav configuration -- they turned down certain update rates to make things work smoothly on the Atom (you can't update quite as fast as a PR2, from which the defaults exist but with the proper update rates, you should be able to run navigation on the Atom).